# just installed tiatracker, but cannot find any way to start it?

Tags: software-installation, tracker

i just installed a atari 2600 music tracker called tia tracker (in repos from ubuntu : tiatracker) after install there is no frikkin way to get the program started. typing tiatracker in the terminal also gives no response. it´s just like if the package is a dummy. how can i start tiatracker anyway ? anyone have the answer ?
(xubuntu 20.04lts)

Comment: The binary executable is apparently named `TIATracker` (note the capitalization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the packages.ubuntu.com website to see the [files provided by the `tiatracker` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/tiatracker/filelist):

- If the package is installed, you can get the same list from `dpkg -L <packagename>`

> File list of package tiatracker in focal of architecture amd64
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/TIATracker
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/README.md
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/README.source
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/TIATracker_manual.odt
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/TIATracker_manual.pdf.gz
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/Talk_Revision/TIATracker_Revision.odp
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/adsr.png
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/changelog.Debian.gz
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/copyright
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/editor.jpg
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/examples/Dok Sae - Speedtest.ttt.gz
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/examples/glafouk - Beside.ttt.gz
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/examples/glafouk - Miniblast.ttt.gz
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/infotab.jpg
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/percussion_no_overlay.png
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/percussion_with_overlay.png
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/screenshot.jpg
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/tt_guide_creator.png
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/tt_icon.png
> /usr/share/doc/tiatracker/tt_instrument.png
> ```

Looks like the package is fully-featured, and includes

- A binary (`/usr/bin/TIATracker`)
- README file
- Manual
- Examples

Recall the Linux is case-sensitive: `tiatracker` is not the same as `TIATracker`

Comment: thank you. it works, i can run the program. omg i feel so noob